# Setting a LIMIT on a query inside a PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a function that wraps a fairly expensive query in a PostgreSQL function:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
  myschema.expensive_fn(search_term text) 
  RETURNS TABLE(
    objectid integer, 
    geom geometry
  ) 
AS 
$$ 
  BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT [... slow query here...];
  END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

I tried invoke this function with a `LIMIT` to make it more responsive in the UI:

```sql
SELECT myschema.expensive_fn('user input') LIMIT 100;
```

But this still runs pretty slowly, which I interpret as being because the expensive query inside the function is being run to completion without a limit. So what I've ended up doing is:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
  myschema.expensive_fn(
    search_term text, 
    lmt integer DEFAULT 100
  ) 
  RETURNS TABLE(
    objectid integer, 
    geom geometry
  ) 
AS 
$$ 
  BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT [... slow query here...]
    LIMIT lmt;
  END; 
$$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' STABLE PARALLEL SAFE;
```

And the query becomes

```sql
SELECT myschema.expensive_fn('user input', 200);
```

This works, but it feels inelegant, especially as some services (e.g. [pg_featureserv](https://github.com/CrunchyData/pg_featureserv)) will set the query limit anyway, which makes the query look really ugly:

```sql
SELECT myschema.expensive_fn('user input', 200) limit 200;
```

So I just wanted to ask whether there's a better way? Is there, for example, some way for a PostgreSQL function to automagically determine whether it is being invoked in a query with a given `LIMIT`?

Comment: What comes to my mind is that you are limiting the result of the internal query to 100 and you are still happy with the result. Aren't those rows (101 and above) meaningful? It's like saying: "To run a marathon in a shorter time, I just run a quarter of it".

Comment: a) try returning a cursor instead b) use an `sql` function, not a `plpgsql` function, as the former can more easily be inlined

Comment: @TheImpaler Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your point. Any time we use LIMIT, it cuts off part of the result space. That's kind-of the point of limit isn't it? And yes, result number `limit + 1` might be useful, that's always a risk with LIMIT. But that comes down to ordering the results as best we can. Fundamentally, the issue I'm trying to solve is that pg_featureserve is setting the limit anyway, but not in way that speeds up my query.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the suggestion to return a cursor, I'll look at that. And changing the language setting - I was following a blog post, I didn't even realise that setting the language differently might have a performance impact!

Comment: @IanDickinson If you are happy to lose part of the result space, then you have two options: 1) Apply the limiting inside the function, as you are doing; you'll see the limiting twice (inside and outside). 2) You can pipeline the result of the internal query, so the external LIMIT will affect it.

Comment: Pipelining the result of the inner query sounds interesting, thanks for the suggestion. I don't think I know how to do that though, any pointers you can suggest as to how best to do that?